# Issue with setting GST Code / Tax Code in Purchase Order by Script

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to change the tax code on the Purchase order from default code to another one for some conditions . I have put the script in the Post Sourcing and it changes the tax code as intended. But when the PO is saved, it puts back the default tax code again!

The code in the Post Sourcing is as below. Any help on this is much appreciated!

```
// Set Tax Code
    function setTaxCode(scriptContext){

        var currentRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;
        var RecType = scriptContext.currentRecord.type;
        var sublistName = scriptContext.sublistId;
        var sublistFieldName = scriptContext.fieldId;
        var line = scriptContext.line;
        if (sublistName == 'item' && sublistFieldName == 'item'){
                var itemType = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:sublistName,fieldId:'itemtype'});
                var item = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:sublistName,fieldId:'item'});
                if (item != '' && itemType != ''){
                  var expAccount = getExpenseAccount(item,itemType);
                  if (expAccount == null)
                    {var expAccountType = null}
                  else
                    {var expAccountType = getExpenseAccountType(expAccount);}
                  if (expAccountType == 'Fixed Asset'){
                    currentRecord.setCurrentSublistText({sublistId:sublistName,fieldId:'taxcode_display', text:'GST:Capital Purchases', ignoreFieldChange: true});
                  }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue was resolved atlast. It turned out that I was 'tricked' by the NetSuite Field Explorer plugin which showed the fieldid as  'taxcode_display' but the actual fieldid is 'taxcode'. The same code worked with changing fieldid to 'taxcode'.

Thanks!